How to integrate GitHub with Gerrit?
I tried the following:
I have installed Gerrit Code Review (3.9.4), using the plugins section installed the "GitHub" plugin. However, I could not locate useful ways to integrate a GitHub repo into this.
I went through documents such as :
https://gitenterprise.me/2013/10/17/gerrit-code-review-or-githubs-fork-and-pull-take-both/
https://gerrithub.io/
Gerrit with Github
All of them refer to the old versions of Gerrit 3.3 built using Bazel
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/dev-bazel.html
They mention about building the plugin: >> How to build this plugin.
However, now the plugin is readily available in Gerrit, but there is no information on how to use it.
Can anyone who has tried this, share how to use the Gerrit GitHub plugin for versions higher than 3.8?

What happened when you followed the steps starting here?
